# RequestError: Error: connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8443

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm querying 127.0.0.1:8443 via request-promise in NodeJS with 10K+ requests and are hitting:

```
{ RequestError: Error: connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8443
```

and/or

```
{ RequestError: Error: read ECONNRESET
```

If I lower my number of requests to say 10-100 there's no error.

Is this my NodeJS-client who are making the requests which cannot keep up, or is it the endpoint I'm trying to requests which cannot keep up?

I have control over both ends, and are not getting any error from the server I'm requesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors):

> ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer): A connection was forcibly
>   closed by a peer. This normally results from a loss of the connection
>   on the remote socket due to a timeout or reboot. Commonly encountered
>   via the http and net modules.

Since a large number of requests are hitting the server, it is getting overloaded *(busy servicing previous requests before it can handle any new request)*.

Possible solutions:

- Check/modify server timeout using `server.timeout = 0`. This is **not a
  recommended solution** for production. However, it can help you in
  development/testing.
- You can increase the maximum number of allowed connections using
  `server.maxConnections` but this too is **not a recommended solution** for
  production. However, it will allow you to verify whether the server hardware
  capacity needs to be upgraded or the network bandwidth needs upgrade.
  If your server is in a good datacenter, usually it is the hardware
  capacity that needs to be upgraded (*see next two solution*).
- If you are using a cloud server, increase the number of cores so that
  requests can be services faster.
- Consider load sharing by having more than one instance of the server
  (behind a load balancer).