# Cloud function return RequestError: Error: socket hang up

Tags: firebase, nodes, google-cloud-functions, onesignal

I have use Cloud function connect with onesignal service which will send notification to user. After test function locally, it's work perfectly but after deploying to the cloud function it return me an error "RequestError: Error: read ECONNRESET" which I thick the cloud function reset the connection

Here is what my code look like

```js
exports.sendNotification = functions
  .pubsub
  .topic('cron-notification')
  .onPublish(async (message) => {
    const databaseRef = admin.database();
    // Query all user from realtime db
    const snapshotsUser = await databaseRef
        .ref(`user`)
        .orderByKey()
        .once("value");

    // Check if user exist
    if (snapshotsUser) {
      //Get the user key
      const user_object_key = Object.keys(snapshotsUser.val());

      // send notification for each user
      user_object_key.map(async (user_id) => {
        // query something
        const snapshotsUser = await databaseRef
          .ref(`record/user_id`)
          .orderByKey()
          .once("value");
        const message = {
          "app_id": "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx",
          "filters": [
            {"field": "tag", "key": "user_id", "value": user_id}
          ],
          "headings":  {"en": `Hello World`},
          "contents": {"en": `Hello`}
        }
        sendNotification(message);
      })
    }
  });

function sendNotification(message) {
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Authorization": "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  };
  
  // Use onesignal for send notification
  const options = {
    uri: "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications",
    headers: headers,
    method: 'POST',
    json: true,
    body: message,
    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
  }

  return request(options).then(response => {
    if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP Error: ${response.statusCode}`);
    } else {
      console.log(response.body)
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

Can anyone give suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for people who face the same problem with me, I just notice that I did not return anything in the function. The cloud function will reset the function if it did not return any thing back. So from the code above should be like this and everything work fine.

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.pubsub.topic('cron-notification').onPublish(async (message) => {
const databaseRef = admin.database();
// Query all user from realtime db
const snapshotsUser = await databaseRef
    .ref(`user`)
    .orderByKey()
    .once("value");

// Check if user exist
if (snapshotsUser) {
    //Get the user key
    const user_object_key = Object.keys(snapshotsUser.val());

    // send notification for each user
    return Promise.all([    user_object_key.map(async (user_id) => {
        // query something
    const snapshotsUser = await databaseRef
    .ref(`record/user_id`)
    .orderByKey()
    .once("value");
        const message = {
            "app_id": "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx",
            "filters": [
                {"field": "tag", "key": "user_id", "value": user_id}
            ],
            "headings":  {"en": `Hello World`},
            "contents": {"en": `Hello`}
        }
    sendNotification(message);
})])}});

function sendNotification(message) {
const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Authorization": "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
};

// Use onesignal for send notification
const options = {
    uri: "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications",
    headers: headers,
    method: 'POST',
    json: true,
    body: message,
    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
}

return request(options).then(response => {
    if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP Error: ${response.statusCode}`);
    } else {
        console.log(response.body)
    }
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors) ‘ECONNRESET’ error occurs when a connection is forcibly closed by peer. This results in loss of connection on the remote socket due to timeout or reboot. Since you mentioned the code is working locally and the error occurs after it is deployed, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890933/requesterror-error-connect-econnreset-127-0-0-18443#answer-41891853) is an answer that says the possible solution is to increase the number of cores so the requests can be serviced faster. Also, it might be useful to read the GitHub discussion on [socket hang up](https://github.com/request/request/issues/2047) error.